# Tax Receipt report Generation from CiviCRM

Tags: cdn-tax-receipts

How do I generate CDN Tax receipts for our agency from our CiviCRM?

Answer (score 4):

Under administer - system settings - extensions, go to the add new tab. Then install CDN Tax Receipts.

Then there'll be a configure page under administer - civicontribute.

Then there'll be a button on contributions to issue single receipts, or you can do it in batch from search results:

Contribution Search -> Aggregate Tax Receipts

Contact Search -> Annual Tax Receipts

Comment: Please note that CDN stands for Canadian but we know people in other countries are using it as well. Oh and the Extension now has automated testing on Github Actions 